# Conditional function change in matplotlib's contour plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, conditional-statements, contourf

I would like to generate a contour plot, using a 2 variable function, Z(X,Y). However, I would like to impose a condition that changes the function when X is less/greater than a certain value. Such a change would allow me to use just a singular `plt.contour` line (i.e I **do not** want to create two separately defined functions, that results in using two separate plotting command lines).
I continue to run into (what I believe to be) truth/logic errors. My guess is that some aspect of the numpy meshgrid does not comply with that conditional "switch" of the function. Attached below is the short code to display the concept, along with the full Traceback error. If anything is unclear, or if what I have provided is insufficient to explain my problem, please feel free to comment below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = np.linspace(0,50,100)
Y = np.linspace(0,50,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)


def z(x,y):

    if x < 20:
        return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)
    
    else:
        return np.tan(x * y)


Z = z(X,Y)


plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.colorbar()
```

````
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-7e200be093e6> in <module>
     16 
     17 
---> 18 Z = z(X,Y)
     19 
     20 plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))

<ipython-input-29-7e200be093e6> in z(x, y)
      9 
     10 def z(x,y):
---> 11     if x < 20:
     12         return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)
     13 

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use [`numpy.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html).
You have to pass:

- a condition as the first parameter
- values from which to choose if that condition is true as the second parameter
- values from which to choose if that condition is false as the third parameter

In this way, your `z()` function becomes:

```
def z(x, y):
    return np.where(x < 20,
                    np.sin(x) + np.cos(y),
                    np.tan(x*y))
```

Generated plot:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Everything is fine but u have to change the comparison on `np.any(x<20)`. It means that if any of the element of x is greater than 20. You can also use `np.all`, if you want to do this just if every element of the array fulfill the condition

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


X = np.linspace(0,50,100)
Y = np.linspace(0,50,100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(X,Y)


def z(x,y):

    if np.any(x < 20):
        return np.sin(x) + np.cos(y)
    
    else:
        return np.tan(x * y)


Z = z(X,Y)


plt.contourf(X, Y, Z)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.colorbar()
```

Comment: Thank you! Although, I am having a bit of difficulty when thinking about whether I should use np.all(x<20) or np.any(x<20) . When using both of these changes, the error goes away which is great! But they both (of course) produce two different plots. Does my situation require one or the other, to your knowledge?

Comment: consider this example, if any(np.any) element of the array is > 0 -> true, if all (np.all) elements of the array are >0 -> in the case below, false
np.any(np.asarray([[1,0,4],[-3,4,-2]])>0) # true 
np.all(np.asarray([[1,0,4],[-3,4,-2]])>0) # false

Answer (score 2):

Truth testing in numpy array is element wise,

```py
import numpy as np
X =  np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(X<3)
```

*output*: [ True  True False False]

You can use **.all()** or **.any()** depending on whether you want **all** or **any** of the elements to satisfy the criterion

```
print((X<3).all())
```

*output* : False